# How to calculate the rightmost 1 and the leftmost 1 in the binary representation of a large number x?

Tags: binary, number-bases

So I have an integer $x$ between $1$ and $2^{64}$ and I am looking for the fastest way to get the rightmost 1 (the least significant bit or LSB) and the leftmost 1 (the most significant bit, MSB). How to do this in Mathematica? Can it be done without branching?

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but wouldn't the leftmost digit be 0 if the number is less than 2^32 and 1 if it is greater, and the rightmost would be 1 if it's odd and 0 if its even...

Comment: The leftmost and rightmost 1 is what we are after

Comment: A lot of CPUs [support this function natively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set), so for ultimate speed I'd recommend going bare-metal by [writing a C function and linking it in](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateLibrary.html).

Comment: `BitLength` for leftmost. As already noted, `IntegerExponent[...,2]` for the rightmost.

Comment: 64-Part[Flatten[IntegerDigits[8649436750036656,2,64]],{1,-1}]  gives {52, 4} in little-endian bit numbering.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`IntegerLength`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerLength.html) and [`IntegerExponent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerExponent.html):

```
SeedRandom[77];

x = RandomInteger[{1, 2^64}]
```

> ```
> 8649436750036656
> ```

```
IntegerDigits[x, 2]
```

> {1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}

```
{IntegerLength[x, 2], 1 + IntegerExponent[x, 2]}
```

> ```
> {53, 5}
> ```

[`IntegerExponent >> Details`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerExponent.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
64-Part[Flatten[IntegerDigits[8649436750036656,2,64]],{1,-1}] gives {52, 4} in little-endian bit numbering.
```

Answer (score 0):

```mma
64-Part[Flatten[IntegerDigits[8649436750036656,2,64]],{1,-1}]
```

gives {52, 4} in little-endian bit numbering.